# iOS 8 self-sizing cells - wrongly calculated height for labels and Infinite scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8

I am trying to get my cells to resize dynamically and I wanted to take advantage of new self-sizing cells in iOS 8. Now, I set constraints to edges of superview and the cells really resizes itself. The problem is that the cell has sometimes wrong height and the text is not displayed all. If the text is longer also the mistake in height of label is greater. I was experimenting if the problem is not caused by newly added margins but it doesn't work either.

When I was trying do the resizing the old way, I discovered that cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize gives also wrong height. There is probably something I am missing in sizing of content view in table view cell, but I can't figure out what it is.

I prepared working example with resizing text and image, for you to test out:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35953801/Cell%20test.zip

EDIT:

There is additional problem, when I try to implement infinite scrolling the reloadTable always scrolls it to the top. When I try to use insertRowsAtIndexPaths instead, it starts to jump to wrong position and glitch very badly.

Here is updated code to test out:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35953801/Cell%20test2.zip

EDIT 2:

So as @gabbler suggested, the best way to make reliable infinite scrolling is to do it the old way. I haven't found way how to use the storyboard prototype cells to measure them in heightForRow method. If you try something like this, you get stuck in infinite loop, because dequeReusableCell actually calls heightForRow:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellProgrammatical", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell
```

It might be possible to set it up with Nib resource for cells, but best will be probably to save yourself a headache, follow https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayout and set up constraints programatically.

There is one thing that needs to be done for iOS8. It adds extra constraint UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height to 44 initially, which breaks the cell if it is taller than that. It's necessary to set all the vertical constraints to lower priority (999).

Here is the example once again, with working infinite scrolling:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35953801/Cell%20test3.zip

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a label in your cell which has **preferred width** being set, remove the setting seems to fix the problem.

Since you have already make the label width to be equal with the cell width, there is no need to set the **Preferred Width**.

And try to remove these code.

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600;
tableView.reloadData()
```

which seems to be redundant here.

Comment: Typically you still want to set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` if the label will be multi-line to ensure the text wrapping happens appropriately.

Comment: @jszumski, so what is your suggestion for this user case?

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. What's the point of estimatedRowHeight than anyway? I saw it in every example code for ios8 self-sizing cell, but it seems it only caused glitches in the beggining.

Comment: I added new subquestion in original post, can you also check it out?

Comment: @TomášKohout, to be able to implement infinite scrolling you might have to use the old way of manually calculate row height, it is jumpy using self sizing cells, I think it will be improved in the future. I tested and it worked on tableview with `heightForRow` delegate method implemented.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I had this problem when I set constraints between my label and the cell *margins* instead of the cell itself. Margins are weird and don't appear to be correctly taken into account when calculating `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`.

Changing my constraints to be attached to the cell itself fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I use the following code to calculate height
Here 20 is my font size

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
NSDictionary *userAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                     NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]};
    NSString *text = self.userModel.quote;

    CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithAttributes: userAttributes];

    ht = 20;

    if (textSize.width > [FunctionUtils getViewWidth]) {

        ht = (textSize.width/([FunctionUtils getViewWidth]));
        ht = (ceil(ht))*20+35;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks,but this works for single labels only. This is just example, in reality there will be more labels and images in the cell.